# Can not enable cors properly in apigateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using API gateway and here is my api gateway:

[image]

So it is just one post method and more details of it is as follows:

[image]

So when I run enable cors I get the following error:
[image]

The issue is related to lack og application/json on 200 response back on the method response as is mentioned in the following link:

[Fail to enable CORS for API Gateway functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820769/fail-to-enable-cors-for-api-gateway-functions)

To fix the issue I tried to add it manually

[image]

Now I added application/json empty. But still when i try to enable cors I get invalid status code specified . Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To resolve this issue method response HTTPS status must be **proxy**.

In integration request settings uncheck and after successful update check again "**Use Lambda Proxy integration**".

[image]

After that *method response* should be changed and look like this:

[image]

Comment: This answer should receive massive respect!! Uncheck and check, then it works!!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem when I was trying a MOCK response before I connect my API to a Lambda function. I have already marked 'Enable API Gateway CORS' as checked at Resource Level and still I was getting CORS error while sending XMLHttpRequest.

I have added header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in 'Method Response' and then set the value of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to '*' under 'Integration Response'. This approach solved this CORS issue.