# How to disable CORS on API Gateway console?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

As I got CORS errors from a website I develop localy, I would like to disable CORS for testing. But there is only an enable switch (which I tried to solve the CORS error).

It is strange as even after manually enabling CORS with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'`, I still get this error:

> from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource

-- added --

I got a bit further in using CORS by hints from this post:
[Fail to enable CORS for API Gateway functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820769/fail-to-enable-cors-for-api-gateway-functions)

It is not enough to enable CORS, but also to add those extra header information.

Anyway, how to disable the CORS afterwards would still be the question.

Comment: we need more information - is this proxy or non proxy information? can you show us the gateway? etc

Comment: It is proxy. I now also created a new hello world from codestar. Even there is cors enabled. Can it be true that one can enable CORS but not get rid of it?